# more info or docs for pyvda, or a better module:

Tags: python

```
import time
import subprocess
from pyvda import AppView, get_apps_by_z_order, VirtualDesktop, get_virtual_desktops

#clockify
subprocess.Popen("C:/Program Files/Clockify/ClockifyWindows.exe")
current_window = AppView.current()
target_desktop = VirtualDesktop(7)
current_window.move(target_desktop)
VirtualDesktop(7).go()
```

trying to load specific programs to specific desktops in windows 11; so, my "clockify" app loads on the desktop "clock" and blender loads on the blend desktop so on so on.
cannot find any docs for this mofo, but pieced together what's above.
it would be awesome to:
a) check if a virtual desktop exist, and create it, incase of accidental deletion.
but really what I need is a way to specify the "current window". right now (i'm assuming python sees the that as whatever window is active as the current window); I have to put the sleep timer inbeteen loading programs, which is fine.
b) need a way to specify what window as active, then i can tie that to the appropriate desktop and maybe load them all at once to save time

#still a newb and no formal training. and alot of aconyms confuse me, and obvious assumptions may not be obvious to me.
cheers,
-mda

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you want.

```py
import pyvda
import win32gui
import time
import os
import psutil
from collections import namedtuple


Application = namedtuple('Application', 'desktop_name window_title application_path')

apps = [
    Application('desktop_one', 'window_title_one', r'C:\path\to\app_one.exe'),
    Application('desktop_two', 'window_title_two', r'C:\path\to\app_two.exe'),
]

for desktop_name in ['desktop_one', 'desktop_two']:
    if desktop_name not in [desktop.name for desktop in pyvda.get_virtual_desktops()]:
        desktop = pyvda.VirtualDesktop.create()
        desktop.rename(desktop_name)


for app in apps:
    startfile = False
    while not bool(len([process for process in psutil.process_iter() if process.name().lower() == os.path.basename(app.application_path).lower()])):
        if not startfile:
            os.startfile(app.application_path)
            startfile = True

time.sleep(0.1)

for app in apps:
    window = [window for window in pyvda.get_apps_by_z_order(current_desktop = False) if app.window_title in win32gui.GetWindowText(window.hwnd)][0]
    desktop = [desktop for desktop in pyvda.get_virtual_desktops() if desktop.name == app.desktop_name][0]
    if window.desktop.number != desktop.number:
        window.move(desktop)
```